# In filesystemwatcher, what are the expected errors the the error event can raise?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I looked in MSDN and in reflector, but couldn't figure it out
usually - i get all this information from the description tags, but in this case - no such luck.

I already figured out with experiments:

> - "access is denied" [Win32Exception, native error code=5] if the watched directory is being deleted
> - "too many changes an once" [InternalBufferOverflowException] if the buffer is overflown.

any more ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There also can be **UnauthorizedAccessException**, when you do not have rights to access folder or specific file.

Also, do not rely heavily on basic **FileSystemWatcher**,even without **InternalBufferOverflowException** it can skip some events and works very,very badly of network directories. You should use combine **FileSystemWatcher** with some polling-style system, for example, run directory scanning every **30** seconds target directory and compare your current, **FileSystemWatcher** based files list, with real situation, that way you'll have MOST of actual information in real time and ALL information periodically.